# Ways to use 'both' in a specific sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these sentences are grammatically correct? Are there even more ways to write the correct ones? Although I'd really like an analysis of why each sentence is correct or wrong, I would be pleased with the shortest of an answer as well. I'd appreciate explanations mentioning noun phrases, determiners and what part of speech 'both' is in these sentences.

It would be useful to note, that deficiency means below 30 and insufficiency below 50 nmol/L of serum 25-hydroxy vitamin D.

A) Both the prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency were found higher in females compared to males.

B) Both of the prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency were found higher in females compared to males.

C) Both prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency were found higher in females compared to males.

D) The prevalence of both vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency was found higher in females compared to males.

E) The prevalence of both deficiency and insufficiency of vitamin D was found higher in females compared to males.

F) The prevalence of vitamin D, both deficiency and insufficiency, was found higher in females compared to males.

G) The prevalence of vitamin D both deficiency and insufficiency, was found higher in females compared to males.

H) The prevalence of vitamin D both deficiency and insufficiency was found higher in females compared to males.

I) Both the prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and the prevalence of vitamin D insufficiency were found higher in females compared to males.

J) Both the prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and the prevalence of insufficiency were found higher in females compared to males.

K) Both the prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and vitamin D insufficiency were found higher in females compared to males.

L) The prevalence of vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency was found higher in females compared to males

M) The prevalence of deficiency and insufficiency of vitamin D was found higher in females compared to males

A'-H', K'-M') Same as the corresponding sentences, but with "prevalence" in plural and "was" replaced by "were" where it is found.

Comment: Assuming *every possible* level of vitamin D represents either "sufficiency" or "insufficiency", I don't understand what it means for *both* levels to be more prevalent in females than males. Do you actually mean ***excess*** and *insufficiency?* At least then it's feasible females could be more prone to *both* deviations (from the third possibility, "just the right level").

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I meant deficiency and insufficiency! You are totally right, I mistakenly typed the wrong word and will correct it right away.

Comment: Unless it's a domain-specific distinction, I'd have said ***deficiency*** and ***insufficiency*** are equivalent. Surely you mean ***excess*** for the other possibility?

Comment: What do 'deficieny' and 'insufficiency' measure? The same thing, or different things?

Comment: Domain-specific ;) Specifically, deficiency is a subset of insufficiency. You are very observant, thank you :)

Comment: They measure the same thing, label different levels of it. Deficiency means below 30 and insufficiency below 50 nmol/L of serum 25-hydroxy vitamin D.

Answer (score 1):

> The incidences of both vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency were found higher in females as compared with males.

"Both" is the first part of the correlative conjunction "both ... and" (compare the "either" of the correlative conjunction "either ... or").

Comment: Greg lee proposal at least complies to the following subject-verb rules: **1)** The sentences where "prevalence" is found only once and using "were" are incorrect. **2)** Sentences using "was" seems incorrect because the subject is plural (we are comparing 2 factors).

Comment: Prevalence is the correct term, I think. That is because we are talking about percentages of people affected, not of the likelihood of it. Also, plural feels a bit off for both words. I think prevalence and incidence are widely used in singular form in papers. I don't quote find it wrong either. Maybe it is a viable alternative. I would put all my cases in plural as well, but that's just unpractical.

Comment: @Graffito 1)I agree. It seems "prevalence" is the subject in those and not "vitamin D deficiency and insufficiency". My mistake was treating "prevalence" like a noun adjunct. Would these sentences be correct if "prevalence" was switched to plural? 2) Funny your sentence here makes the same mistake. Is that intentional? Because it's awesome! Anyway, in these sentences the subject is "prevalence" and not the noun phrase followed by "both".After some thought I think "prevalence" should be plural in those sentences. It could be singular, if deficiency and efficiency shared the very same prevalence

Comment: @Graffito So, your 2) would be correct if it said "should" instead of "is". I was thinking, saying "The case of both Tom and Jerry." would imply they share one case. By the same logic, "prevalence" is wrong, because that's not what I want to imply. Supporters of the singular form used in papers say "prevalence" is an adjective, but it is clearly a noun to me and opposers. I'll be editing my question soon. I'd like to hear more in favor of the term incidence.

Comment: @NickZafiridis - Shame on me! in 2) i made the exact mistake I identifiy in the text :(

Comment: Don't fret. That sentence is the perfect example of itself, making it easier to understand. It's also one awesome coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

"Both" here seems to refer to "deficiency" and "insufficiency", so it needs to link these two words. You're stuck in your examples with the phrase "prevalence of vitamin D", but aren't you really talking about the prevalence of deficiency and insufficiency?

So I'd write: "The prevalence of both deficiency and insufficiency of vitamin D was found to be higher in females than in males."

Is that what you wanted to say, though?""

Comment: You are quoting sentence E, so I guess that one is correct. It is indeed "the prevalence of deficiency"(I'll be using this word instead of "sufficiency", corrected it in the question as well) and insufficiency. Vitamin D acts as a noun adjunct of those two. Essentially, instead of saying "deficiency of vitamin D", I am saying "vitamin D deficiency". If sentence E using the former is correct, then at least one sentence using the latter should be as well.

Comment: By the way it feels right, but what is the grammar mechanism, which allows for the "of vitamin D" to be used only after "insufficiency" and not after "deficiency" as well in that sentence? The subject of "was found" is prevalence, right? What is the noun phrase containing "both"? Which are the noun phrases in general in that sentence?

Comment: _What is the grammar mechanism, which allows for the "of vitamin D" to be used only after "insufficiency" and not after "deficiency" as well in that sentence?_ The use of "both"?

Comment: But such reductions are met in other sentences too: "I like fruit, chocolate and vanilla cakes." So what is the common denominator, the underlying grammar mechanism?
Also, such a reduction can lead from sentence I to A, right(this sentence is another example btw)? So sentence A would also be correct?